# R: Change certain cells of a data.frame to bold

Tags: r

I have looked for a while but cannot find an answer to my question: How can you edit particular cells of a data.frame to be bold or italic or whatever?

I have a correlation matrix named `corHighViewSOI` (see below) and would like to convert the highest 6 entries to be bold.

```
row.names    Jan        Feb        Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1   Jan 1.00000000  0.56691659  0.5768323   0.4576408   0.03780489  0.15176883  0.05791961  -0.07543212 -0.11203950 0.07805176  0.06893252  -0.06780511
2   Feb 0.56691659  1.00000000  0.5505371   0.4271174   0.06137921  0.04427556  0.04681803  0.10396901  0.01804741  0.10406845  0.09379290  0.02160785
3   Mar 0.57683233  0.55053712  1.0000000   0.5767771   0.18408866  0.23747621  0.15080239  0.18517667  0.20887256  0.28660763  0.22042098  0.20300788
4   Apr 0.45764084  0.42711743  0.5767771   1.0000000   0.38408853  0.26066824  0.38564495  0.35326341  0.38841728  0.37860488  0.26967989  0.29615529
5   May 0.03780489  0.06137921  0.1840887   0.3840885   1.00000000  0.53754314  0.52842071  0.57477819  0.56916596  0.48388783  0.29378609  0.45386730
6   Jun 0.15176883  0.04427556  0.2374762   0.2606682   0.53754314  1.00000000  0.71967821  0.57044572  0.60215610  0.62047854  0.39541672  0.53483997
7   Jul 0.05791961  0.04681803  0.1508024   0.3856450   0.52842071  0.71967821  1.00000000  0.76574102  0.73829198  0.66729781  0.45893665  0.60664549
8   Aug -0.07543212 0.10396901  0.1851767   0.3532634   0.57477819  0.57044572  0.76574102  1.00000000  0.84522485  0.66523923  0.54960411  0.64963081
9   Sep -0.11203950 0.01804741  0.2088726   0.3884173   0.56916596  0.60215610  0.73829198  0.84522485  1.00000000  0.74064734  0.62288570  0.70391806
10  Oct 0.07805176  0.10406845  0.2866076   0.3786049   0.48388783  0.62047854  0.66729781  0.66523923  0.74064734  1.00000000  0.64529608  0.65560997
11  Nov 0.06893252  0.09379290  0.2204210   0.2696799   0.29378609  0.39541672  0.45893665  0.54960411  0.62288570  0.64529608  1.00000000  0.64267924
12  Dec -0.06780511 0.02160785  0.2030079   0.2961553   0.45386730  0.53483997  0.60664549  0.64963081  0.70391806  0.65560997  0.64267924  1.00000000
```

I can isolate the highest using

```
corHighViewSOI[!1:l %in% corHighSOI] <- NA
```

which replaces all values except the highest 6 with `NA`, but this is not very pretty and so would prefer to highlight the highest 6 in bold.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Do you mean for inclusion in a report or something? Or do you mean displayed at the console?

Comment: Do you mean using [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)?

Comment: `head()` function will only display the first 6 values of a variable.

Comment: Displayed at the console and also stored so that when I click on it in the environment it is as described. I don't know what markdown is I will have a look. And `head()` does not seem to be what I am looking for, it simply returns the table up to a certain number of rows.

Comment: It has just occurred to me that R may not be very good at making pretty tables, and I should be using a different program if and when I need to export the table to a report. Is this the case?

Comment: @boro141 As a matter of fact, R is excellent for making publication-quality tables but (as almost with everything else in R) you will have to use special packages to deliver the results. You should explore `pander`, `knitr`, `xtable` and other relevant tools. In practice, if you decide to use Stata you will arrive at the same problem of producing quality tables via user-written programmes. Similarly SPSS and SAS seldom meet all requirements for generation of publication quality materials. The abundance of the relevant packages makes R an excellent tool, contrary to major proprietary software.

Comment: And for a correlation table like you are presenting, another option is to use a heatmap using `ggplot2`. You could include the values only in cells that fit your criteria, this may be preferable to a very large table of values.